# Sticky header jumps when scrolling in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css

There's a sticky red bar in a container in the middle of a page. I want this red bar to stay on top when scrolling down and stop before the end of the grey container. Without using position fixed for the collapsed red bar (which caused some problems when I tried it), how can this be accomplished without the red bar jumping in Internet Explorer? Here's a much simplified version of what I am working on to demonstrate what I have so far.

http://codepen.io/codingninja/pen/aKmno

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
var initialHeight = 0;
var wrapperHeight = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  wrapperHeight = $('.wrapper').outerHeight();
  initialHeight = $('.sticky-header').outerHeight();
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var stickyContainer = $(".sticky-header");
  var containerTop = $(".wrapper").offset().top;
  var containerDistance = containerTop + wrapperHeight;
  var containerLength = stickyContainer.length;
  if(containerLength > 0) {
    var currentPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = initialHeight;
    if(currentPos > containerTop && currentPos + initialHeight < containerDistance) {
      stickyContainer.addClass("collapsed");
      stickyContainer.css("top", Math.max(0, $(this).scrollTop()-containerTop));
      $('.filler').css("height", height);
    }
    else {
      stickyContainer.removeClass("collapsed");
      stickyContainer.css("top", "auto");
      $('.filler').css("height", 0);
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Position fixed actually does work, but there is one case where it is inconsistent in Chrome and Firefox in regards to widths within the sticky header for what I am working on. It's not in the demo, but this issue may be able to be solved with some thinking.

CSS change

```
.collapsed {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

JQuery

```
var initialHeight = 0;
var wrapperHeight = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  wrapperHeight = $('.wrapper').outerHeight();
  initialHeight = $('.sticky-header').outerHeight();
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var stickyContainer = $(".sticky-header");
  var containerTop = $(".wrapper").offset().top;
  var containerDistance = containerTop + wrapperHeight;
  var containerLength = stickyContainer.length;
  if(containerLength > 0) {
    var currentPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = initialHeight;
    if(currentPos > containerTop && currentPos + initialHeight < containerDistance) {
      stickyContainer.addClass("collapsed");
      $('.filler').css("height", height);
    }
    else {
      stickyContainer.removeClass("collapsed");
      $('.filler').css("height", 0);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution is still not perfect. The sticky jumps when it reaches a certain point in scrolling.